# c mmap - how to know how many pages reserved

Tags: c, mmap

If I reserve memory with mmap, how can I know how many pages has mmap reserved?

Do I have to divide length with page size or is there another way?

Comment: Well that's one way.  But out of curiosity, why do you need to know the number of pages?

Comment: I am writing malloc implementation for a school project which uses mmap to reserve memory.

Comment: What does that have to do with the number of pages?

Comment: If for example I get two pages of memory I have much more available memory than if I only get one. How else can I get a total number of memory mmap reserved?

Comment: @oliva5: If `mmap` is successful, it gives you the number of bytes you asked for. If the amount you asked for is not a multiple of the page size, there may be some waste. (It may reserve more, but the extra is not available for your use.) If you want to avoid waste, use `sysconf` to get the page size and only make allocations in multiples of it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to make sure no memory gets wasted after mmap call for school project. I will do as you suggested and use sysconf to get page size and allocate memory using multiples of it. This way I will also always know how much memory I have available.